# d3 and mathjax, rendered output disappears

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mathjax

Example codepen here: http://codepen.io/Lett1/pen/EVrWRo?editors=011

I'm creating a tree diagram and want to add simple fractions to each node, I import mathjax and append foreignObjects like this (ignore the static text):

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
.attr("height",100)
.attr("width",100)
.text("$$ \\frac{2}{3} $$")
```

When the codepen loads/refeshes, you can see the rendered formula pop in and dissappear shortly after, why does that happen?

Comment: This looks like https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/279.

Comment: You might try switching to the SVG output.  But if you do, you should change from display delimiters (`$$...$$`) to inline delimiters (`\(...\)`).  You can use `\(\displaystyle{...}\)` if you want dispaystyle layout.  Of course, you need to double the backslashes if it is used in a string literal.